# Manage vertical ViewPager inside ScrollView

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am developing an app which it has a vertical ViewPager within ScrollView. The thing is ViewPager only recognize touch events when I scroll horizontally, otherwise ScrollView will get focused and perform the scroll.
I think this could work:

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            int action = event.getActionMasked();

            switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But because of ViewPager does not recognize touch events when I perform vertical scroll this piece of code does nothing.
What I want to achieve is give focus to ViewPager when I touch it and give focus to ScrollView when I'm not touching the ViewPager. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I use for a scrollview that has problems with textviews focusing.  It might help you.  It might not.

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svRecord);
    sv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    sv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
    sv.setFocusable(true);
    sv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```